# check if a string contains a digit in python

Tags: python, regex

I am checking a string in python for a digit. I have used the is_digit() method but doesnt look like it works.
this is my string 302 E 34th 101
so i want to check if the last split of the string is a digit and if true,cut it and assign it to a value.
here is my code

```
if split("302 E 34th 101")[-1].is_digit():
  digit=split("302 E 34th 101")[-1]
```

this doesnt seem to work as expected since it does not return result.
Does anyone know the best way to do this? maybe using a regular expression?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, you're splitting it first, so you're trying to check if "101" is a digit. I think you want `is_numeric`. Also, please read [mcve] because I don't know what your split function does.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you are using a custom `split` function which doesn't split the string properly. Instead you can use `str.split` method and use `isdigit()` for validating the digit format:

```
>>> s.split()[-1]
'101'
>>> s.split()[-1].isdigit()
True
```

Answer (score 1):

That's just not how you split in python. You need to call the method on the string object like this:

```
if "302 E 34th 101".split()[-1].isdigit():
    digit = "302 E 34th 101".split()[-1]
```

[Here's a link to the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Answer (score 0):

You can `rsplit`or `rfind` if you always want to check based on whitespace:

```
s = "302 E 34th 101"
print(s[s.rfind(" "):].isdigit())

print(s.rsplit(None,1)[-1].isdigit())
```